# Desativar botões do ASPxRichEdit

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxrichedit

Na minha aplicação, uso o componente **ASPxRichEdit**, que é um editor de texto cheio de botões para salvar, abrir, alterar a fonte, etc. Porém, não quero que alguns botões como o *Open* e *Save*, por exemplo, fiquem visíveis ao usuário. Como posso escondê-los?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui com a seguinte *markup*:

```
<dx:ASPxRichEdit ID="ASPxRichEdit1" ClientInstanceName="rich" style="width: 100%; height: 600px" runat="server" WorkDirectory="~\App_Data\WorkDirectory" OnCallback="ASPxRichEdit1_Callback">
    <Settings Behavior-Open="Hidden" Behavior-Save="Hidden"  Behavior-SaveAs="Hidden"></Settings>
</dx:ASPxRichEdit>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adicione este código no evento PreRender:

```
[C#]
    @Html.DevExpress().Spreadsheet(settings => {
        settings.Name = "Spreadsheet";
        settings.PreRender = (s, e) => {
            DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpreadsheet.ASPxSpreadsheet spreadsheet = (DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpreadsheet.ASPxSpreadsheet)s;
            spreadsheet.CreateDefaultRibbonTabs(true);
            DevExpress.Web.ASPxRibbon.RibbonTab fileTab = spreadsheet.RibbonTabs[0];
            fileTab.Groups[0].Items[0].ClientEnabled = false;
            fileTab.Groups[0].Items[1].ClientEnabled = false;
        };
    }).GetHtml()
```

[Referência Aqui!.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T147705/spreadsheet-disable-new-and-open-buttons-in-ribbon-menu)

Comment: Aparece 'ExportOptionsPropertiesNames.Html' dos not contain a definition for 'DevExpress' por causa da primeira linha...